# WooCommerce- Order Details Thank You page Add Random Number for each product?

Tags: woocommerce

I am stuck on one problem, for my E-commerce website after placing order on i want to show random number for each product in order details section.
I have tried this : in theme(function.php)

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'add_unique_id');
```

then

```
function add_unique_id($order_id) {
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items(); 
      foreach ($items as $item_id => $product )
     {
        $gen_id ="Hi Dad!";
      wc_add_order_item_meta($item_id, 'unique_id', $gen_id);
     }
```

But by using this i am not getting unique number for each product.

I want to add random number in below red portion in image of Thank You page.

[image]

please help to resolve.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If you have already done with the adding item_meta_data into the cart, hopefully, you can easily make it visible into cart too?

It is not that necessary but just for the testing purpose.
For this, you can use "`woocommerce_get_item_data`"

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'mwb_wgm_woocommerce_get_item_data', 10, 2 );

function mwb_wgm_woocommerce_get_item_data($item_meta, $existing_item_meta){

    //by using $existing_item_meta , find your unique_key (whether it is displaying or not)

    foreach ($existing_item_meta as $key => $val ) {

        if($key == 'unique_key') {
            $item_meta [] = array (
                    'name' => __('RANDOM KEY','your_slug'),
                    'value' => stripslashes( $val ),
            );
        }
    }
    return $item_meta;
}
```

Let me know is your UNIQUE KEY is displaying there or not?

Comment: I am able to generate key in cart as well as Review order but after placing order it is not showing in thank you page

Comment: i am getting unique no by using your code, i have printed this in array it looks like
'[data:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3595
                            [key] => _unique_nos
                            [value] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 75816
                                )

                        )'

How should i print this ?

Comment: Can you show me your cart's screenshot, how it is displaying? I don't need the array, just the cart item.

Answer (score 1):

There are the various issue can be there
 1. wc_add_order_item_meta (Woo version < 3.0.0)

If you're thinking to add item_meta to each of your product and then yes it will get displayed automatically on Thank You Order Page.

Please use "$item->add_meta_data('Your_Key',$order_val);" [WC_version >= 3.0.0]

2. Please make sure you've already set that "key" to your cart_item_meta by using this hook -> "woocommerce_add_cart_item_data".

Hope this may help you :)

Comment: thanks for answer can you please elaborate in brief. i have created key like
'add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'filter_add_cart_item_data', 10, 4 );
function filter_add_cart_item_data( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id, $quantity ) {
    if ( ! isset($cart_item_data['unique_key']) ) {
        // Make this item unique
        $cart_item_data['unique_key'] = md5( microtime().rand() . "Hi Dad!"  );
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}
'

Comment: Twari how to implement this

Comment: Please check my next answer

Comment: IF you successfully able to display the keys, then it will get automatically displayed over your Thankyou Page too